# Microsoft Office Interop - Converted PDF file size issue

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

I am converting DOCX file to PDF file using below code (Microsoft Office Interop).  Recently we have created new server and notice that PDF file size is increasing. When we convert same DOCX file to PDF into both server at that time new server's PDF file size is higher than old server's PDF file.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document _wordDocument;
_wordDocument = _wordApp.Documents.Open(ref DocxFilePath);
_wordDocument.Activate();

object o_format = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;
_wordDocument.SaveAs(ref PdfFilePath, ref o_format);

object oFalse = false;
object nullobj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
_wordDocument.Close(ref oFalse, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_wordDocument);

_wordDocument = null;
```

Both server have same version of Office (MS Office 2016).

Any suggestion/idea to rectify the problem are most welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not really a good idea is to automate Word on the server-side. Here is what Microsoft clearly states:

> All current versions of Microsoft Office were designed, tested, and configured to run as end-user products on a client workstation. They assume an interactive desktop and user profile. They do not provide the level of reentrancy or security that is necessary to meet the needs of server-side components that are designed to run unattended.
>
> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.
>
> If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that and possible alternatives in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) article.

Instead, you may consider using the [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) if you deal with open XML documents only.

If you're doing document generation on the server-side and you don't need to be working with Office documents as output, you'd generally use something like [iText](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) or [iTextSharp](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp), which would render the PDFs directly.